# tkinter Listbox.bbox method returns None after scrolling listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm trying to make a listbox that shows tip when moving cursor over it, to enable that I  create a class like this:

```
class CreateToolTip(object):

    def __init__(self, widget, text='widget info'):
        self.waittime = 300  # miliseconds
        self.wraplength = 180  # pixels
        self.widget = widget
        self.text = text
        self.widget.bind("<Enter>", self.enter)
        self.widget.bind("<Leave>", self.leave)
        self.widget.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.leave)
        self.id = None
        self.tw = None
        self.disp_thread = Thread

    def enter(self, event):
        self.schedule()
        global base_x, base_y
        base_x, base_y = event.x_root, event.y_root
        t = self.disp_thread(target=self.wait_and_disapr)
        t.start()

    def wait_and_disapr(self):
        sleep(3.5)
        self.hidetip()

    def leave(self, event=None):
        self.unschedule()
        self.hidetip()

    def schedule(self):
        self.unschedule()
        self.id = self.widget.after(self.waittime, self.showtip)

    def unschedule(self):
        id = self.id
        self.id = None
        if id:
            self.widget.after_cancel(id)

    def showtip(self, event=None):
        x = y = 0
        x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox(0)       # exception line
        x += base_x
        y += base_y
        # creates a toplevel window
        self.tw = tkinter.Toplevel(self.widget)
        # Leaves only the label and removes the app window
        self.tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)
        self.tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        label = tkinter.Label(self.tw, text=self.text, justify='left',
                              background="#ffffff", relief='solid', borderwidth=1,
                              wraplength=self.wraplength)
        label.pack(ipadx=1)

    def hidetip(self):
        tw = self.tw
        self.tw = None
        if tw:
            tw.destroy()
```

then I initialize an instance with Listbox object:

```
lstbox = tkinter.Listbox(*args, **kwargs)
lstbox_tip = CreateToolTip(lstbox, text=tip_info)
```

Things went well when the listbox is not scrolled vertically, the tips showed up as cursor moved over listbox, but when I scrolled down the listbox, tips didn't show as normal and following exception occured:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "DYRecorder-ttkVersion4.0-distribution.py", line 617, in showtip
    x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox(0)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

It seems that Listbox.bbox method returns None after scrolling the listbox. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: what sort of solution do you expect? `bbox` is defined to return nothing if the item isn't visible. When you scroll the listbox, item 0 is off screen and thus bbox returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bryan Oakley's comment and explanation from this [link](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.bbox-method), I got the tip to show when listbox is scolled by modifying the showtip() method, here's what I add:

```
def showtip(self, event=None):
        x = y = 0
        index_lst = [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]  # my listbox has 20 elements
        for index in index_lst :
            if self.widget.bbox(page):
                x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox(page)
                break
        x += base_x
        y += base_y
        self.tw = tkinter.Toplevel(self.widget)
        self.tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)
        self.tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        label = tkinter.Label(self.tw, text=self.text, justify='left',
                              background="#ffffff", relief='solid',
                              borderwidth=1, wraplength=self.wraplength)
```